# Creating functions (Liberty Basic)

Tags: arrays, function, populate, basic

EDIT:

Ok I got how arrays work and that part seems to work. Im still having a problem with the functions. I do not understand how functions work correctly. I need to put something in the ( ) obviously but I dont understand what. You can see I have

```
search=findmonth()
```

Im not sure if that is even a good code to use I then have it where it calls up the function but of course because I dont know how to do functions it doesnt work. If someone can explain how functions work that would be great. All the information I have makes it really confusing and doesnt show real examples that explain anything.

This is the assingment, put it in code just so its smaller

```
Create two arrays

1.  Monthname$(12)    This array contains month names such as “January”, “February”, etc

2.  MilesDriven(12)   ‘ This array contains the miles driven for the month.


Notice that the MonthNames$(12) array is a string array while MilesDriven(12) is numeric array.

•    Write a program to display the menu with the following options and ask for the user input.

                    Type P to populate miles and month name.
                    Type S to search for Month.
                    Type M to search for Month name with smallest Miles
                    Type L to search for MonthName with Largest Miles
                   Type E to exit.

•   •        If the user types P.

o     Populate all the  arrays.

•   •        If the user types S then:

o   Ask the user for the Month Name.

o    Search the array for that Month Name and find its position in the Monthname array.


o    Display the MonthName$, and MilesDriven at the position found during the above search.

•   •        If the user types M then: 


o    Search the array for  the smallest miles in MilesDriven array  and  find its position.

o    Display the MonthName$, and MilesDriven at the position found during the above search.


•   •        If the user types L then:

o    Search the array for the largest Miles in MilesDriven array and  find its position.

o    Display the MonthName$, and MilesDriven at the position found during the above search.


•        If the user types E. then:

o    Terminate the program.

•        If the user types any other option:

o   Display the message “Invalid Choice. Try again” and go back and display the menu.

PS: You program must keep displaying the menu until the user types the option E, to exit the program."
```

This is the code I have so far.

```
Dim MonthNames$(12)

MonthNames$(1) = "January"

MonthNames$(2) = "Febuary"

MonthNames$(3) = "March"

MonthNames$(4) = "April"

MonthNames$(5) = "May"

MonthNames$(6) = "June"

MonthNames$(7) = "July"

MonthNames$(8) = "August"

MonthNames$(9) = "September"

MonthNames$(10) = "October"

MonthNames$(11) = "November"

MonthNames$(12) = "December"

Dim MilesDriven(12)

Search=Findmonth()
E=0

While E = 0

    Print "Press P to populate miles and month name"

    Print "Press S to search for Month"

    Print "Press M to search for Month name with smallest Miles"

    Print "Press L to search for MonthName with Largest Miles"

    Print "Press E to exit"

    Input Answer$

    Select Case Answer$

    Case "P", "p"
        For position = 1 to 12
            Print "Enter the amount of miles driven in "; MonthNames$(position)
            Input MilesDriven(position)
        Next


    Case "S", "s"

        Function Findmonth()
            Print “Please enter a month you want to search for”
            Input Month$

        For position = 1 to 12
              If (Month$ = MonthName$(position)) then
                      Print "You have driven "; MilesDriven(position); " "; "in the month of " MonthNames$(position)
                      Exit for
              End if
        Next

        If (position > 12)  then
                   Print “Please enter a valid month”
        End if

        End function


    Case "M", "m"



    Case "L", "l"




    Case "E", "e"

        E=1

    Case Else

      Print "You made a wrong selection. Please enter again"

    End Select

Wend
For position = 1 to 12
    Print MonthNames$(position)
    Print MilesDriven(position)
Next

Print "Goodbye"

End
```

Comment: when you put sample code in your question, indent it by 4 spaces so that it appears as a code block in the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to populate the miles into the month array, rather you have two arrays side by side, such that Monthnames$(i) is the month name and MilesDriven(i) is the miles for that month.

Note that, reading your assignment's instructions, this "populating" should only happen when the user types "P", so move the initialising of your arrays into your Select statement like this:

```
Dim Monthnames$(12)

Dim MilesDriven(12)

E = 0
While E = 0

    Print "Press P to populate miles and month name"
    Print "Press S to search for Month"
    Print "Press M to search for Month name with smallest Miles"
    Print "Press L to search for MonthName with Largest Miles"
    Print "Press E to exit"

    Input Answer$

    Select Case Answer$
    Case "P", "p"
        Monthnames$(1) = "January"
        Monthnames$(2) = "February"
        Monthnames$(3) = "March"
        Monthnames$(4) = "April"
        Monthnames$(5) = "May"
        Monthnames$(6) = "June"
        Monthnames$(7) = "July"
        Monthnames$(8) = "August"
        Monthnames$(9) = "September"
        Monthnames$(10) = "October"
        Monthnames$(11) = "November"
        Monthnames$(12) = "December"
        MilesDriven(1) = 10
        MilesDriven(2) = 20
        MilesDriven(3) = 30
        MilesDriven(4) = 40
        MilesDriven(5) = 50
        MilesDriven(6) = 60
        MilesDriven(7) = 70
        MilesDriven(8) = 80
        MilesDriven(9) = 90
        MilesDriven(10) = 100
        MilesDriven(11) = 110
        MilesDriven(12) = 120
    Case "S", "s"
        Rem - put search by name here
    Case "M", "m"
        Rem - put search by for smallest miles here
    Case "L", "l"
        Rem - put search by for largest miles here
    Case "E", "e"
        E=1
    Case Else
       Print "You made a wrong selection. Please enter again"
    End Select
Wend
Print "Goodbye"
End
```

Comment: Ok I see. Im usually having the user input stuff so I assumed that is what he wanted but reading I see that isnt. Just to be clear, if the user searches for a month, say april, the 4 will be conntected to the other 4 giving us 40?

Comment: Yes - you can reference both arrays using the same index (4) when you want to print out values.  Re user input - maybe I mis-interpreted and at 'P' you are meant to prompt the user for miles driven for each month?

Comment: Now im not sure...lol I mean he usually has us have the user input information. Im not sure if English is his first language so it could be he wants us to do that. Ill try and work on it tomorrow and figure everything out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok I have the array and everything worked out. Im now stuck on functions which I had a problem with last time as well. I edited my original post to show what I have so for and where im stuck.

Comment: You should not re-write your question to become a new question since other people might have the same problem and want to understand the answers - that is one of the main features of Stack Overflow.  Instead you should raise a new question.  Before you do that, I suggest you attempt to solve it yourself - you will get criticised on Stack Overflow if you have not done your research into your own problem.  Do a google search on defining functions in Basic or refer to the documentation you've received.  Also, you are meant to up vote an answer or accept an answer if it helped solve your question.

Comment: Ok sorry. I was just going to ask another question but I thought since it still pertained to this that just changed the question would be easier and not flood the site. I also tried up voting your answerer. It says I need more reputation. The material we were given is beginning programming for dummies. The book says "Function FunctionName(Data) 'instruction ' FunctionName = Value Then is shows what it looks like Answer = cube(3) Print "The cube of 3 is = "; Answer End Function cube(x) cube = x * x * x End function. Ill try google some more but it mostly shows the same thing.